# Should I use Wordpress to skin a database website?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am going to start programming a website which allows users to post adverts for aircraft for sale. (Think autotrader for planes). It will be free to use. There are a few websites that do this already but they are all flawed for different reasons.

I am comfortable using php and mySQL so plan to use these to do the 'back-end'. I am also competent with HTML as a language but am terrible at graphics and making these look pretty. Therefore I would like to use some form a 'skin' to place over the code I build.

I have considered using Wordpress as there are many free themes which are aesthetically pleasing. I have never used Wordpress before. I know it is a database website already. Is it suited to having custom databases/webservices built behind it and displaying search results etc...

OR...

Can I use the database that comes with it as the information store and allow users to create accounts and post items etc...

Any thoughts/advice welcome.

Comment: If your site is CMS heavy (for example you want the full content management or blogging functionality) then WP will save you a lot of work. However, if you think your project will be development-heavy, then WP isn't particularly elegant in its internal approach, and you're better off with a framework. That would be Symfony2, Zend, CodeIgniter etc.

Comment: (Just so you know, although you can glean bits of help for discursive questions like this in the comments, since there is not a definitive answer, they will usually be closed. It's not that it's not a good question, it's just not a good fit for the site).

Comment: I think this might have a chance on WP.Stackexchange where they are a bit more liberal on open-ended questions AFAIK. I'll ask a mod to migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress is an ecosystem of its own, and it's pretty fat in terms of memory use and existing APIs and structures.

Integrating this huge behemoth with a lean back-end that you have already built on your own won't make much sense unless you *specifically* want to use WP's back-end functionality instead of yours.

WordPress themes are just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, so anything a WP theme does, you can achieve in your app as well - it's "just" a question of effort. Starting to use Wordpress just because of a nice-looking WP theme won't make sense as the effort of integration will very likely be much more than what you save by using the theme.

If however you're considering using *WP as the back-end* (say, using custom post types for aircraft entries, etc.) that is a totally valid path to go. Again though, it has pitfalls as well as advantages, and the ability to use some nice-looking WP themes shouldn't be the only factor in your decision.

Comment: OP: yeah, agreed. If the theme is the only draw for WP, it'd be only a small amount of work to do something similar in a framework's layout. You could farm this out to another developer, it should only take them a few hours to a day, depending on complexity.